# Change font-size with media queries

Tags: css, media-queries, responsive

I want to change the font size of a table header.
It should be large when the application is view at the desktop and become smaller when shown on a mobile phone.

```
th {
  @media screen and (max-width: 699px) {
    font-size: xx-large;

  }  
  @media screen and (max-width: 700px) {
    font-size: small;

  }  
  
}
```

I am not quite sure if this is the right way.

Comment: Look up the syntax for media queries. MDN is a good source. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to write this way

```
th {
    font-size: xx-large;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 699px) {
   // write any CSS code here.

  th {
    font-size: xx-large;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you have to write the **TH** style inside the media syntax
[For more details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6370690/media-queries-how-to-target-desktop-tablet-and-mobile)

```
@media only screen and (max-width : 700px) {
th
{    font-size: small;

  }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

The way to do this is to style the `th` element as you would have it on the large screen and then set the media query to apply a different style for smaller screens.

```
th{
  font-size: large-font-size;
}
```

Then now write the different styles to be applied on smaller screens.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 700px) {
    font-size: smaller-font-size;
  }
```